# Dynamics AX 2012: Dynamically create a class

Tags: c#, clr, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Is it possible to write an x++ (or C# CLR) method that dynamically creates a new class object and/or methods in the AOT?

```
makeCustomClass(string className)
{
    //create new class with name className;
    //populate methods into that class;
}
```

I'm not even sure where to start on this one, so some sample code would be a big help.

Comment: Found an article that may be exactly what I need.  http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2006/11/today-i-want-to-write-about-using-class.html  Will post as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
static void MakeClass(Args _args)
{
    ClassBuild  classBuild;
    DictClass   dictClass;
    ;
    classBuild = new ClassBuild("TRN_ClassBuild", false);
    classBuild.addMethod("test",
        @"void test()
        {
            ;
            print 'Hello';
            pause;
        }");

    classBuild.addMethod("test2", 'void test2()\n{\n}');
    classBuild.addSourceToMethod("test2", @"
        str testVar;
        ;
        testVar = 'TRN_ClassBuild';
        info('We created a Class ' + testVar + ' and can use its methods.');
        TreeNode::findNode('Classes\\'+TestVar).AotNewWindow();");

    classBuild.classNode().AOTcompile();

    box::info(strFmt("Creating class %1 with 2 methods. Code of method test2:\n\n%2", classBuild.name(),
        classBuild.getMethodImplementation("test2", false).AOTgetSource()));

    dictClass = new DictClass(className2Id(classBuild.name()));
    dictClass.callObject('test2', dictClass.makeObject());
}
```

Plagiarized from the following article, then uplifted to work in AX 2012 R2.  http://kashperuk.blogspot.com/2006/11/today-i-want-to-write-about-using-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You have good examples on the **Product Builder** classes (*PBA* prefix) as PB creates some classes for the models during compilation process.

Comment: Also take a look in the XppSource class. There are some 'snippets' there that you can use.